# `tcconfig` throws ValueError when setting/deleting traffic control on docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, trafficshaping

I'm using `tcconfig` to set traffic control rules on docker containers.

I'm running from a python script with `venv` (not from a bash shell) a `tcset`/`tcdel` command, for example:

```
tcdel --docker <container_name> --all
```

The command is run with `check_call` of `subprocess` module.

When I run the command I get an exception thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<base_dir>/venv/bin/tcdel", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "<base_dir>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tcconfig/tcdel.py", line 148, in main
    return TcDelMain(options).run(is_delete_all)
  File "<base_dir>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tcconfig/tcdel.py", line 61, in run
    for tc_target in self._fetch_tc_targets():
  File "<base_dir>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tcconfig/_main.py", line 43, in _fetch_tc_targets
    self._dclient.create_veth_table(container)
  File "<base_dir>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tcconfig/_docker.py", line 127, in create_veth_table
    return_code = self.__create_ifindex_table(container_info.name)
  File "<base_dir>/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tcconfig/_docker.py", line 227, in __create_ifindex_table
    peer_ifindex=int(peer_ifindex_prefix_regexp.sub("", peer_ifindex)),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'vethd94cf85'
```

It seems there's an error in `tcconfig`'s resolving of docker interface name
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to run the `tcconfig` commands with the flag `--tc-command`.

This gives you a list of the `tc` commands to run.

Another issue when running this for dockers with multiple interfaces is that you might get the same bulk of commands more than once, so you might have to filter duplicates.